# Bonjour Not Resolving Hostname

Tags: wifi, networking

We've been having some trouble with connecting to the Pi using Win7 and Bonjour.

This is what happens:

1. Connect to the pi over ethernet.  Ping can get a response from raspberrypi.local
2. Setup wifi and connect to a local wifi network.
3. Disconnect ethernet cable from the Pi.
4. Ping the Pi over the network at raspberrypi.local.  No response.  The PC can't seem to find the Pi over wifi.

Reconnecting over ethernet, the PC can find the Pi.  But not when the ethernet is disconnected.

The Pi is connected over wifi to the network, and we can find the IP number on the wifi network.  We just can't find or resolve raspberrypi.local on the network.

IE the PC was able to connect to the Pi when the IP address of the Pi on the wifi was explicitly used instead of raspberrypi.local.

I think this might be more of an issue with Bonjour than the Pi, but I wanted to see if anyone had trouble resolving a bonjour address, and how they solved it?

Comment: what happens if you ping raspberrypi? Some people have reported removing the Ethernet cable brings down the WiFi network. Are you sure you are still connected after removing the Ethernet cable? Can you ping google or 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Note sure.  The Wifi dongle is still blinking the same color indicating it's active.  How could I test that?  We always run the Pi headless,but I guess we could setup and test with a monitor and keyboard?

Comment: A simple ping of google.com and if that does not work ping 8.8.8.8 can be done via SSH

Comment: After doing a little more research, I wonder if it's IPV6?  this is not usually activated by default on Raspbian.  Could that be it?

Comment: it is possible.

Comment: So I have upgraded all of our images to have ipv6.  It seems to help with establishing connections.  Great idea, thanks!  The problem does still occasionally occur.